# API DEMO MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the API DEMO **MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java*.  I'm new to programming and trying to figure out how to set the path to a local video stored in the raw folder.  Can someone provide how to reference this file?  Thanks.

```
private void playVideo(Integer Media) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {

        switch (Media) {
            case LOCAL_VIDEO:
                /*
                 * TODO: Set the path variable to a local media file path.
                 */
                path = "";
                if (path == "") {
                    // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                    Toast
                            .makeText(
                                    MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this,
                                    "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity, "
                                            + "and set the path variable to your media file path."
                                            + " Your media file must be stored on sdcard.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

Comment: It's not clear for me: you want to playback file from `res/raw` folder (as you say) or from sdcard (as your code says)?

Comment: LOL. Sorry, I'm new to this and didn't realize that the code was referring to the SD card.   Here's the actual APIDemo from the android dev site that I'm trying to get working with a movie in the raw folder.  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html   How do I modify this to reference the local resource?  Thanks. :-)

Comment: Then my answer should help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open raw resources by using resource id. If the file name is "test.avi" then something like this should work:

```
getResources().openRawResource(com.YourProject.R.raw.test);
```

But that is for reading the file, so if you want to open the file with media player then I think you should put it in SD card. Then you can get the path with:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.avi";
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, I figured how to open a file in `raw` folder with `MediaPlayer`:

Change this:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
```

To this:

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, com.YourProject.R.raw.test);
```

Comment: How do I reference this in the code above (if possible)?  I'm trying to get the APIDEMO from here working: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html.   I tried setting path = openRawResource(com.YourProject.R.raw.test); (with referencing my resource) but it gave an error that I needed to create the openRawResource method.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to put `getResources().`

Comment: Btw, I think external applications cannot access your apps `raw` folder. So you should forget about raw folder and put the video in sd card and use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.avi"`

Comment: What if the video is part of the app? It's an app that's going to have training videos.  (I know including videos will make the app huge). :-)

Comment: Thanks LAS_VEGAS!  I'm not sure if it worked because it's not installing on the emulator (video might be too big), but I'm not getting an error now so that a great start!  I appreciate the help!

Comment: It won't let me yet. It says I need to build my reputation to 15. :-)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you might want to take a look at the method [AssetManager.list()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list%28java.lang.String%29)